# Efficiently iterating successive elements of a transposed matrix (via bit operators)

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Let's consider matrices which are internally represented as a 1 dimensional array. 
For instance a matrix(3, 4) is really an array (of say type double) or 3*4 elements. Here is the 'memory layout' of the matrix:

```
00 01 02 03
04 05 06 07
08 09 10 11
```

As such it's very easy to iterate (row by row, left to right) over all the elements of the matrix: it's just an 32-bit integer going from 0 to 11. This is what the transpose looks like:

```
00 04 08
01 05 09
02 06 10
03 07 11
```

What is a (fast) algorithm that taking as input **a single** 32-bit integer representing the i-th element of the transposed matrix (row by row, left to right) returns the index corresponding to the internal representation? By single I mean that an 'incremental' algorithm is not what I'm looking for, the function just take as input a single 32-bit integer (plus number of rows and columns) and output a single 32-bit integer. I mentioned bit-wise operators as it's likely to be the fastest way to solve the problem but any efficient solution suffice really.
In the example above:

```
0 --> 0
1 --> 4
2 --> 8
3 --> 1
4 --> 5
5 --> 9
6 --> 2
...
```

Also, what restrictions (if any) need to be imposed on the number of rows and columns (we already have that num_row*num_col fits in a 32-bit integer) so that the algorithms is guaranteed to work.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends. If the matrix is a power of two in both dimensions, it's easy (just swap two bitfields). Otherwise, it's problematic.

Comment: where "problematic" is `j = i / c; k = i % c; return k * r + j;`, which, despite the division, doesn't leave a ton of room for improvement. If you use unsigned types and `c` and `r` are known at compile time to be constant powers of 2, the compiler probably will derive the version that twiddles bits.

Comment: I suspected the power of 2 would be easier, but I was looking for a generic solution for the arbitrary dimension case.

Comment: Btw, aside for the last element I seem to be able to use one '%' and one '*' per index (provided r*c is pre-computed), but the potential for overflow concerns me.

Comment: i.e., multiply by r and mod out by r*c-1, which maps both 0 and r*c-1 to 0. If you're targeting x86, you most likely won't pay twice for the / and % with the same divisor.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the dimensions remain small, you can use a constant as a lookup table:

```
0x4cd0b73a62951840 >> (x*4)) & 15
```

If they get slightly larger, you could split this into e.g. generating the upper and lower bits of the result:

```
((0x00fea540 >> (x*2)) & 3) | (((0x00924924 >> (x*2) & 3) << 2))
```

Eventually though, the straight-forward approach will be faster.